# How to convert output in Matlab into excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

i made a program, but i need to convert it in excel file, this is my code:

```
in=-1:3;
[a,b,c]=meshgrid(in);
z=a.^2+b.^2;
ac=sort(abs([a(:) b(:) c(:)]),2);
[f,g,h]=unique(ac,'rows');
cnt=histc(h,1:max(h));
disp([a(g),b(g),c(g),z(g),cnt])
```

please help me guys thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as .csv format (use csvwrite function)  and open it in excel(If my knowledge is right ,office does open up .csv format in excel )

Comment: i need the output to be displayed in excel file

Comment: how please provide an example